# Odoo 11 - Adding custom fields to Sales - Quotations

Tags: odoo

I need help with creating a custom method using custom created fields in Sales module when creating a new quotation.

How do I modify this view?

Thank You Guys!

[image: Sample picure from odoo demo, here I added extra 3 fields]

Comment: Read this one:https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html

Comment: If you are still confused, text me@Void